# unable to assign data to wysihtml5 using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

by using `$('.textarea').wysihtml5();` I am unable to fetch data and without using it. Is it possible to fetch?

so i want to fetch data using `wysihtml5();` I am receiving value in response[0].paragraph as "hhsdfdssdf"

```
$('#paragraph').val(response[0].paragraph);
$('#paragraph').attr('value',response[0].paragraph);
$('#paragraph').html(response[0].paragraph);
$('#paragraph').append(response[0].paragraph);
$('#paragraph').text(response[0].paragraph);
```